# How do I join the results of a command substitution?

Tags: zsh, command-substitution, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

I want to create a list of mp3 files like `a 1.mp3|a 2.mp3`.

I have tried `echo ${(j:|:)$(echo *.mp3)}` and some variations of it, but they don’t work:

```
# too much splitting 
01|The|Magic|Finger|01.mp3|02|The|Magic|Finger|02.mp3|03|The|Magic|Finger|03.mp3|04|The|Magic|Finger|04.mp3|05|The|Magic|Finger|05.mp3|06|The|Magic|Finger|06.mp3

# too much quoting
01 The Magic Finger 01.mp3 02 The Magic Finger 02.mp3 03 The Magic Finger 03.mp3 04 The Magic Finger 04.mp3 05 The Magic Finger 05.mp3 06 The Magic Finger 06.mp3
```

I don’t want to create functions or variables for doing this. (It can be trivially done.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit silly to get the list of mp3 files, pass them to `echo` so it can print them separated by spaces, then transfer that output over a pipe, read it, split on space/tab/newline/NUL, and then join with `|`.

Either do:

```
printf '%s|' *.mp3
```

Or

```
files=(*.mp3)
joined=${(j:|:)files}
```

If the purpose is for that to be used as a `zsh` pattern, you'll probably want to escape the wildcard characters in the names of those files. That is done with the `b` parameter expansion flag:

```
pattern="(${(j:|:)${(b@)files}})"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way to do this, but it’s still rather convoluted for such a simple use case:

`echo ${(j:|:)"${(@f)$(print -l *.mp3)}"}`

Comment: This will break on files that contain newlines.

Comment: @Jesse_b If we should have a command to print them NUL separated, we can use `(@0)`. I myself don’t have paths with new lines.

Comment: @Jesse_b, or backslash or that start with -. Here, you could do `printf '%s\n'`. You could do `printf '%s\n' ${(j:|:)${(0)"$(printf '%s\0' *.txt)"}}`, but again that feels quite silly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to glob those files into positional parameters and then `"$*"` to expand them with your desired field separator:

```
set -- *.mp3
(IFS=\|; echo "$*")
```

Note this is being done in a subshell so the changes to IFS don't affect your current shell.

Comment: I know, but I want to do it with substitutions and expansions.

Comment: Unnecessary and not as robust but if you really want to you could do `set -- $(echo *.mp3)`.  This will break on files with whitespace though.  You could also arbitrarily do `echo $(IFS=\|; echo "$*")` but there is no reason to do that.

Comment: I mean I want it done all in one line. Like my own answer. 

Comment: Virtually any group of shell commands can be done on one line with a liberal application of `;`